# How can I select week numbers via the RichFaces calender?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying this:

```
<rich:calendar id="calendar" value="#{calendarBean.week}" datePattern="ww">
```

but all I'm getting is the literal string 'ww' after selecting a date.

'w' is the correct format pattern for "Week in year" according to the Javadoc though:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

I also tried the format pattern 'WW' just for testing purposes ("Week in month", according to the Javadoc), but same result, after selection I'm only getting the literal string 'WW' placed into the input field.

What am I missing?

Comment: The week patterns are not supported (the date is formatted on client-side)

Comment: I would intuitively expect support for the same patterns client-side in a JSF application where most data is drawn from server-side models anyway (such as patterns), otherwise we introduce a mismatch and possibly even code duplication in business logic. Wouldn't it make sense to add them?

Comment: I suppose the need for week numbers wasn't expected but you're welcome to file a feature request. Though I don't see where you're expecting code duplication.

Comment: I mean if we need to handle special cases for special patterns not supported client side, this moves business logic for those to the client and in the worst case duplicates them because we need server side validation anyway.

Comment: On a side note, is there a way to "patch" the RichFaces release I am using without actually forking the official code and maintaining my own version? I think I found the relevant code there: https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/3da3ff7b84d1c21acd35c979f84a721a4606793a/components/rich/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/org.richfaces/calendar.js#L969 But can't wait for it to make it into the next release

Comment: It's JavaScript, you can overwrite the function in your application (you're looking for [this one](https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/master/components/rich/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/org.richfaces/calendar-utils.js#L274)). You cannot share code between Java and JavaScript so there will be duplication in that regard.